# How to select entire block in IntelliJ on MacOS?

Tags: intellij-idea

So assume I have some code block within parenthesis

```
    fun someRandomFun(){

       // some code 

    }
```

now I want to select this entire code block included within parenthesis. What is the shortcut for this operation?

Answer (score 1):

Move the caret just after the *start parenthesis* and then click  **`Shift` + `Option` + `Command` + `}`**

We can start this selection even from *end parenthesis*.

Move the caret just before the *end parenthesis* and then click  **`Shift` + `Option` + `Command` + `{`**